# Tag-based access control with service-linked roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to implement tag-based access control (TBAC) for an ECS task execution role. Basically, I would like to create a service-linked role to be assumed by an ECS task and based on the tags on that task I want to grant access to SSM parameters. This is what the IAM policy for that service-linked role looks like:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameterHistory",
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:<accountNumber>:parameter/config/${aws:PrincipalTag/AppName}/*"
            ],
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

The tags on the task and the path in SSM match, but I still get this error message:
`assumed-role/taskExecutionRole/<someRoleId> is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParametersByPath` on the path specified in `Resource` above.

I would assume that using PrincipalTag with a service-linked role where:

```
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
```

should work fine, but it isn't working at all and I'm struggling to find documentation on how this is actually supposed to work and whether or not it is supported.

Comment: Your policy is based on some reference? Do you have any link to that?

Comment: It's a very simple policy, as you can see above, so no particular reference. It works fine if it is added to an IAM user, but not when it's assumed by a service.